# How to create a temporal series object in a day/hour format and predict values for next day?

Tags: r, temporal

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Date         Price1  Price2  Price3    Price4   .... Price 24

2017-10-15   60.43   49.40   48.72    48.32 
2017-10-16   38.09   30.00   24.47    24.88 
2017-10-17   48.80   46.76   46.73    45.82
```

The goal is to turn the dataframe object into a temporal series, predicting as well the date 2017-10-18, with all the corresponding 24 price/values.

Actually, I get the ts object, but it appears the following error at time to compute Error in ets(stock_prize) : y should be a univariate time series

Any advice?

Comment: You can reshape from wide to long, combine date and time to create datetime column, store as time series, then forecast on the ts object

Answer (score 0):

I think your data structure is not correct. I suggest you should make those dates a factor and make only one column for the values. For example you have something like this:

```
mydates <- as.Date(c("2007-06-22", "2004-02-13"))
mydates2 <-as.Date(c("2008-06-22", "2005-02-13"))
mydates3 <-as.Date(c("2009-06-22", "2006-02-13"))
hours <- c(8,9)
values <- c(1,2)
a=data.frame(mydates,mydates2,mydates3,hours,values)
a
```

This is how your data looks:

```
   mydates   mydates2   mydates3     hours values
1 2007-06-22 2008-06-22 2009-06-22     8      1
2 2004-02-13 2005-02-13 2006-02-13     9      2
```

But you should transform them to look something like this:

```
dates=c(mydates,mydates2,mydates3)
hours_factor=rep(hours,3)
ordered_values=rep(values,3)
b=data.frame(dates,hours_factor,ordered_values)
b
```

This is how your data shoud look like:

```
 dates             hours_factor ordered_values
1 2007-06-22            8              1
2 2004-02-13            9              2
3 2008-06-22            8              1
4 2005-02-13            9              2
5 2009-06-22            8              1
6 2006-02-13            9              2
```

After that you can make the variables a ts class. You can use ts function for that. If you want to predict next date value you can do an auto-regression. It is very well documented in the Internet, but please know your data have to match some requirements first.